# Can $f(x) = |x-y|^k$ be expressed as a summation for $x$ and $y$ in the complex plane?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

Let $x, y \in \mathbb{C}$ and let $k \in \mathbb{N}$. It is possible to expand the function

$$
f(x) = |x-y|^k
$$

about $x = 0$ and obtain a summation identity in the form $f(x) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \dots$?

Comment: No, for your $f$ is nowhere analytic (unless $k=0$)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Ok, to be more precise, initially I had two variables $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the function I am interested in is $f(x) = ||x - y||^k$. I thought by 'converting' to the complex plane I could write the function in an expanded form. For example $\log||x -y||$ can be expressed as $\log||x -y|| = \text{Real} \log|x-y| = \text{Real}\bigg(\log(x) - \sum_{j=0}^\infty \bigg(\frac{y}{x}\bigg)^j\bigg)$ when you convert to the complex plane. So it seems strange that something similar can't be done for $f(x) = ||x - y||^k$ which seems like a more straightforward function?